# bar plot transparency not working

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm plotting two frequency bar graphs on top of each other and I would like to make one of the bar graphs transparent. I've tried this:

```
[n,xout] = hist(data1,10); %Use 10 bins for the histogram
B1 = bar(xout,n/sum(n),'b'); %relative frequency is n/sum(n)
hold on
[n,xout] = hist(data2,10); %Use 10 bins for the histogram
B2 = bar(xout,n/sum(n),'r'); %relative frequency is n/sum(n)
ch = get(B2,'child');
set(ch,'facea',.4)
```

However, the second plot graphed does not seem to be transparent. Is there something I'm missing?

**Edit**

output of `get(B2)`:

```
Annotation: [1x1 matlab.graphics.eventdata.Annotation]
             BarLayout: 'grouped'
              BarWidth: 0.8000
              BaseLine: [1x1 Baseline]
             BaseValue: 0
          BeingDeleted: 'off'
            BusyAction: 'queue'
         ButtonDownFcn: ''
              Children: []
              Clipping: 'on'
             CreateFcn: ''
             DeleteFcn: ''
           DisplayName: ''
             EdgeColor: [0 0 0]
             FaceColor: 'flat'
      HandleVisibility: 'on'
               HitTest: 'on'
            Horizontal: 'off'
         Interruptible: 'on'
             LineStyle: '-'
             LineWidth: 0.5000
                Parent: [1x1 Axes]
         PickableParts: 'visible'
              Selected: 'off'
    SelectionHighlight: 'on'
          ShowBaseLine: 'on'
                   Tag: ''
                  Type: 'bar'
         UIContextMenu: []
              UserData: []
               Visible: 'on'
                 XData: [1x10 double]
             XDataMode: 'manual'
           XDataSource: ''
                 YData: [0.5333 0.1778 0.0444 0.0889 0.0889 0.0222 0 0.0222 0 0.0222]
           YDataSource: ''
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `B2` does not have any children so `ch` is empty (at least in R2015B).

You can change the `FaceAlpha` property directly using for example

```
B2 = bar(xout,n/sum(n),'r','facea',.4);
```

instead of looking for its children.

Comment: When I try this, I get this error: `There is no facea property on the Bar class.`

Comment: oh shoot.  What about `FaceAlpha`?

Comment: mhh I'm really puzzled. Can you add to your question the output of this command: `get(B2)`

Comment: Me too.. I've added the output of `get(B2)` to my original question

Comment: What about you create a [histogram](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) with your data? Then you should be able to modify the `FaceAlpha` property

Comment: You're probably right. I should switch to just using a frequency histogram instead of a bar plot